# "get one's head around" vs "get one's arms around"

Tags: differences, idioms, word-usage

I have seen both idioms used in practice. The definitions I found,

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+arms+around,  and http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+head+around

don't indicate much difference between the two and do not give any clue as to when one is more appropriate than the other.

The only significant distinction in the definitions is that "get one's head around" is mentioned as "informal", whereas "get one's arms around" is not.

- Is this distinction accurate?
- Are their others, both in term of meaning and usage?

Comment: One phrase is more conceptual, the other more physical.

Comment: @Wayfaring Stranger : interesting. That's what I thought intuitively, but it is not clear at all from the above definitions and the examples therein, hence my puzzlement.

Comment: I've *never* come across figurative use of the "arms" version used in the sense of "understand". It doesn't really make any sense unless I see it as a "twice-removed" metaphoric extension from figurative ***grasp = understand***, but I don't see why a competent speaker would want to do that. I think it's essentially a "copying error" from less competent speakers.

Comment: As I witness downvotes, I suspect the question might not be fully appropriate here. I am not a big user of ELU, so I am not quite familiar with the standards for questions here, but I'd be happy to learn. If you have time, feel free to tell me which standards you think are not met in the question, or to redirect me to posts in the meta discussing these standards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree that they are the same.

In my mind, "get one's head around" is about conceptual problems, whereas "get one's arms around" is about more physical things or actually "doing" stuff.

For example, I might say *"I'm having problems getting my head around this task."* meaning that I'm struggling to conceptually understand what I'm doing.

On the other hand, I might say *"I'm having problems getting my arms around this task."* meaning that I'm struggling to complete the actual task (but not because I don't understand).

As you can see, the distinction I draw is not a bright line in the sand, but I would say that it's consistent with how I've seen it used.

Comment: Thanks. Once again rather at odds with the examples presented in the links above, but it might just indicate that the site is a bad references.

Comment: @MartinVanderLinden I don't think it makes the site a bad reference at all.  Idioms, by their very nature, are hard to define.  Also, there are a lot of regional variations with idioms that are almost impossible to catalog.  My experience may just be a function of my location in the world, and not actually indicative of the "common" definitions of those idioms.

Comment: Point taken. I guess I would still expect a good reference to warn me about vaguenesses and to mention a couple of different regional variations, if any. To make a parallel with etymology : "true" etymology is by nature hard to establish, and there are different theories which are sometimes impossible to catalog. I do not expect a good etymological reference to be exhaustive, but I still expect it to warn me about the existence of competing theories, and to list -- and ideally discuss -- a couple of them.

Comment: @MartinVanderLinden No dictionary claims to be completely exhaustive.  Built in to every single definition is exactly the caveat you want made explicit.  If the editors of the dictionary were aware of a competing theory or definition, I assure you they would have included it.  But asking for complete (or even just near-complete) awareness of all aspects of all regionalisms of all dialects of English is just too much.

Comment: @Nick2253, what do you hear more often in the US- get one's head around or wrap one's head around (or wrap one's mind around, for that matter) ?

Comment: @Daniel I definitely hear "wrap" far more often than "get".  I think "get" is somewhat commonly used with head, but "mind" is used almost exclusively used with "wrap"

Answer (score 1):

Getting/wrapping your arms around something is an old expression, something my dad used back in the '60's and my coworkers used in the '70's and '80's.  It means to involve yourself in an assigned project (or job) to the extent that you are industriously engaged and providing leadership.  The figurative image would be something like initially wrestling with, but eventually picking up and carrying an awkward and heavy load.   Often the expression is used in the negative, to indicate that someone still needs to get their arms around something, implying that a person doesn't have a grasp on the project or job requirements and needs to get that figured out urgently.

Wrapping your head around something is a more recent term, derived from getting/wrapping your arms around something, and is more limited to only the understanding of project or job requirements.  It usually does not include the additional components of taking actions to move the team towards success.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).